# Most Secure Way to Store Uploaded Files

Tags: symfony

I store uploaded files in the web directory:

```
//src/Acme/CocoBundle/Entity/CocoFromTheNorth.php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{

    return 'uploads/documents';
}
```

Is this a good practice? Wouldn't it be better to keep uploaded files outside the web directory so that they cannot be directly accessed by the users?

Am I right to think that the best way would be to store uploaded files outside of the web root? Where would it be the best then?
Or how could I configure the web server to deny access to the uploads directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's preferred to keep uploaded files outside of the web directory and use `X-SendFile` to serve those files after you established the access permissions using PHP.

I've outlined something similar here: [How to securely store files on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530001/how-to-securely-store-files-on-a-server/10530250#10530250)

And here: [Caching HTTP responses when they are dynamically created by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596116/caching-http-responses-when-they-are-dynamically-created-by-php/10596231#10596231)